# Can an Artificer Armorer use Enhanced Defense Infusion on their Homunculus Servant (infusion)?

Tags: dnd-5e, artificer, artificer-infusions

Can an Artificer Armorer use Enhanced Defense Infusion on their Homunculus Servant (infusion); same goes for the Battle Smith's Steel Defender? Do these constructs/creatures Natural Armor even count as Armor to apply the infusion?

Enhance Defense = +1 AC to Armor or Shield & Homunculus Servant (infusion) has a Natural Armor of 13 and Steel Defender has a Natural AC 15

Would HS's AC be 14 + Dex mod and SD's AC be 16 + Dex mod?

Comment: Ah I understand now. In that case this might be a partial duplicate of this question:

https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/164907/can-a-battle-smiths-artificer-steel-defender-be-imbued-with-an-infusion?rq=1

Answer (score 4):

#### No.

The rules for infusions state:

> Artificer infusions are extraordinary processes that rapidly turn a nonmagical object into a magic item.
>
> The description of each of the following infusions details the type of object that can receive it, along with whether the resulting magic item requires attunement.

The description of the type of item requires for Enhanced Defense is:

> *Item: A suit of armor or a shield*

Since the Steel Defender and Homunculus Servant are not “a suit of armor or a shield”, you cannot infuse them with Enhanced Defense.